# Advice about best way to assign a value from a .json to a $scope.variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

My current code is highly inefficient.

- Create a function that manually assigns a value to a variable for each "item" I need to be translated
- Repeat for each each language

What I would like to do is this:

- Create a development-only function that:

  - Creates a list of items
  - Push that list into a .json file for each language of which the function will be aware I'm supporting (and created in such a way I'll just fill it)
- Manually edit each .json file
- Fetch the corrisponding .json file called by a function and use it to populate my `$scope.variable`s

Before I try to achieve that, is there a better way to handle what I'm needing? If not, could you provide a starter point? To be specific, I don't know how to create a .json in such a way I need just to fill it with values.

My current code that I want to improve is this:

```
app.controller('languagesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.lang = window.navigator.language || window.navigator.userLanguage;
    $scope.setItalian = function() {
        $scope.english = 'Inglese';
        $scope.italian = 'Italiano';
        $scope.cart = 'Carrello';
        $scope.menu = 'Menu';
        $scope.cta = 'Nuova collezione strumenti';
    };
    $scope.setEnglish = function() {
        $scope.english = 'English';
        $scope.italian = 'Italian';
        $scope.cart = 'Cart';
        $scope.menu = 'Menu';
        $scope.cta = 'Check out new products!';
    };
    if ($scope.lang === 'it' || $scope.lang === 'it-it' || $scope.lang === 'it-IT') {
        $scope.setItalian();
    } else {
        $scope.setEnglish();
    }
    $scope.setLanguage = function(changeLang) {
        if (changeLang === 'en') {
            $scope.setEnglish();
        } else if (changeLang === 'it') {
            $scope.setItalian();
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: advice: don't reinvent the wheel. Use [i18n](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) with AngularJS. Localization is a serious problem and there exist good solutions for that

Comment: +1 to @KirillSlatin , also check the https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate best-in-breed i18n plugin

Comment: That is over-complicated for what is my project, despite it is a pretty nice solution, but it's the reason why I discarded them before starting my own code. I'm fine with fetching and using blocks of text or just words :)

Comment: Oh wait, angular-translate seems pretty straight-forward, I think I'll give it a try

Comment: Well, third comment in a row because I can't wait to sum all in one. angular-translate seems the good-looking brother of what I was doing, but still there's a lot of copy and paste.

Comment: Your project is "too small" for proper solution now. You can't know how it evolves. Besides sticking to proper (well-known) patterns allows you to learn something that is well-accepted in IT world and you might use it later

Comment: Well, that isn't all my project. I've opted for a small and simple solution because I know how much will grow THIS project. Beside this, thank you for your thought about that well-know pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont want use angular-translate, You can use something like this:

```
app.controller('languagesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.lang = window.navigator.language || window.navigator.userLanguage;
    $scope.message = {}

    if ($scope.lang === 'it' || $scope.lang === 'it-it' || $scope.lang === 'it-IT') {
        $scope.setLanguage('it');
    } else {
        $scope.setLanguage('us');
    }
    $scope.setLanguage = function(lang) {
        $http.get('language/' + lang + '.json').then(function(result) {
            $scope.message  = result.data;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Right now I can't play with your code, but it seems what I was asking for, thank you!